# How to loop through checkboxes when they're ticked with other values linked

Tags: php, arrays, loops, checkbox, hidden

I can't seem to properly work through this list I have. I have x tables with number of rows between 10 and 200. Each row represents an item, and if you select one or more checkboxes, it loops through those and updates/adds/deletes rows where needed. How would I go about doing this?

I currently have a hidden field with id[], and two checkboxes with own[] and special[]. The ID is obviously the unique item ID, and the two checkboxes represent whether you own a normal version or a special version (or none, or  both). When I loop through them, all IDs are echoed but I can't seem to connect the values of the two checkboxes to them. A simple for loop won't work, because all IDs are echoed, and therefore the checkboxes are not properly looped through.

I'm somewhat knowledgeable about PHP, so hit me with what you've got!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to make bidimensional arrays (if I understood well). You can also forget the hidden field :

`checkboxes[<?= $id ?>][own]` and `checkboxes[<?= $id ?>][special]`. You shall have such an array in php :

```
$_POST['checkboxes'] => array(
                         1 => array(
                              'own' => 'on'
                         ),
                         3 => array(
                              'own' => 'on',
                              'special' => 'on
                         )
                    );
```

Here you have checked "own" checkbox for id "1" and "own" and "special" checkboxes for id "3".

Comment: Very well, that's very clear. Looping through the $_POST['checkboxes'] with a foreach(* as $c) {}, but how to get the ID it's all about? I get ["own"] = "on", but no clue how to find that precious, precious ID. :(

Comment: Woops, finally got it. Rather than using foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $c) {}, which renders you unable to retrieve the original ID the checkbox had, you use foreach($_POST['checkboxes'] as $id => $c) {}, which has $id as the KEY value, and $c the actual content. Thanks for helping me getting on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

The end product:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="product[<?php echo $product['id']; ?>][own]" /> <!-- this is row 20 of the database -->
<input type="checkbox" name="product[<?php echo $product['id']; ?>][own]" /> <!-- row 64 -->
<input type="checkbox" name="product[<?php echo $product['id']; ?>][special]" /> <!-- row 127 -->
```

Upon submitting, this code:

```
foreach($_POST['product'] as $id => $p) {
    echo "ID: ".$id." - Own: ".$p['own']." - Special: ".$p['special']."<br />";
}
```

will produce this result:

```
ID: 20 - Own: on - Special:
ID: 64 - Own: on - Special: 
ID: 127 - Own: - Special: on
```